# Как вставить изображение в TextPane

Tags: java

У меня есть `jTextPane` и `button`, хочу реализовать систему смайликов. Вообщем когда жмём на кнопку то сразу ставится картинка(смайлик) возле текста. 
Нашел информацию что нужно поставить `jTextPane1.ContentType("text/html");`
А далее информации 0, или я просто плохо искал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class HTMLPane extends JFrame {
    public HTMLPane() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane edit = new JTextPane();
        edit.setContentType("text/html");

        URL imgUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image.png");
        String html = "<html><body>"
                      + "Some text "
                      + "<img src=\"" + imgUrl + "\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\">"
                      + "</body></html>";
        edit.setText(html);

        getContentPane().add(edit);

        setTitle("Test");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HTMLPane();
    }
}
```

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, все работает только добавляются картинки по типу "ошибочных", путь к файлу указан верно, формат файла png

Comment: Учтите, что `getResource("image.png")` ищет файл image.png в пакете класса.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает, можно еще вопрос? Зачем нужен getContentPane(), можно как-то без него обойтись ибо у меня есть готовый jFrame в котором много объектов и при выполнения этой функции половина объектов закрывается былым фоном.

Comment: Можно и без него. По большому счёту это рудимент. До Java 5 нельзя было просто вызывать add на JFrame, нужно было получить сначала получить content pane.

Comment: Да, все исправил, простите за столь наглость но если вас не затруднит самый последний вопрос: Теперь все работает и перед тем как добавить картинку я сохраняю старый текст, а потом после него ставлю картинку. Вот только почему-то не работает подозреваю потому что текст простой а не html-овский)) и тогда я делаю так 

    stringImg = jTextPane1.getText();
        String html = "<html><body>"
             + stringImg
             + "<img src=\"" + imgUrl + "\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\">"
             + "</body></html>";
        jTextPane1.setText(html);

но ничего не работает.